# Unable to start mongod in mongoDB 6 in macOS Monterery

Tags: mongodb, macos

When I try to start the service it gives me these errors, and then terminates.

`{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.0","gitVersion":"e61bf27c2f6a83fed36e5a13c008a32d563babe2","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.6.0"}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/System/Volumes/Data/data/db"}}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.729+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.729+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.729+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.730+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-09T21:13:41.730+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}`

Answer (score 0):

`{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}`

I think you're running your mongod on a port that is already in use. Make sure that a port you specify is free (default ones are started from 27107 and then incremented on 1 for each rs/sharded and etc nodes)